# Best MailServer For Apache/CentOS

Tags: apache, centos, mail-server

Trying to configure a mailserver on Linux has proven to be a real pain.

So far, I have installed Postfix and Cyrus on my server, Installed MailX to handle sending mail from terminal, but that only enables mail to be sent from the terminal window, and doesn't recieve mail.

The obvious end-game here is to have a mail server setup that can receive and send new messages @ mike@mydomain.com or any other email addresses I wish to setup in-boxes for.

Does anyone know of any solutions they have come across in the past. I am trying to avoid setting up a server managers like cPanel, zPanel or Plesk. I have moved away from those solutions, and am learning to manage my sites on my own in terminal, but mail is the one thing I really haven't been able to figure out.

I don't want fully written tutorials or anything from you guys, just some friendly links to other answers or articles written about this, because I am truly coming up with nothing on google.

I could just be searching the wrong thing.

PS - Go ahead and move this question if it's in the wrong place, I try not to post at ServerFault, they always tell me my questions aren't professional enough.

Answer (score 1):

I've found qmail to be fairly easy to install and manage, both for inbound and outbound mail.  Also, it's been around since the dinosaurs, and there have never been any security vulnerabilities discovered with it.  Just about everything you need to know about installing it and running it can be found at the site lifewithqmail.org.  See http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#installation for a good step-by-step guide to installing qmail and setting it up.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a ton! I have been reading about iRedMail, have you heard good or bad things about it?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with iRedMail.  But, I'm part of a team of people that runs a system that processes 10's of thousands of incoming and outgoing emails/day.  We run qmail on about a dozen servers, and it's been rock solid and fairly easy to manage once you get familiar with it.  lifewithqmail.org will be your best friend if you decide to go with qmail, and the author of that site (Dave Sill) also wrote a book called 'The qmail Handbook', which is also very good.  Good luck!

Comment: Awesome! There doesn't seem to be a command for "yum install TheBestMailServerEverAndConfigureIt", trust me, I've tried lol

Comment: No, no such command like that for qmail.  But, trust me, install procedure that I gave you in the link above is not too bad if you know your way around Linux.  Have fun!